# C# Single Deployment project for 32-bit and 64-bit application

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit, setup-deployment

I am creating a deployment project. 
I would like it include automatically the correct Solution Platform for the primary output(.exe) and correct content files (32-bit or 64-bit) depending on the Solution platform.

Currently, the setup project displays and error when building a Setup project where its
TargetPlatform in incompatible with the projects target plat form (e.g. x86 vs. x64)

According to some threads, the only way to create deployment application 32-bit or 64-bit projects is to
create separate Setup projects for the 32 and 64 -bit respectively
Are there any ways we could just create a single deployment projects for all target playform?

regards,

Comment: I haven't used VS setup projects, but I have seen that most people simply release both a 32 bit and 64 bit setup.  There may be a way to do a combined solution, but I haven't seen many people do that.  In fact, it might make sense to separate them because in some cases you might want to install both side by side.  Also, as AndrewS mentioned, be sure you can't simply use `Any CPU` as your target for your assemblies before continuing down this path :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what "Any CPU" config is for (rather than x86 or x64). I usually debug with x86 though since Edit and Continue is disabled in 64 bit mode.

Comment: This is true about assemblies, but he is asking about deployment (which admittedly doesn't really have a lot to do with C# or .Net).

Comment: He is talking about Deployment projects which do not have an any cpu option for target platform